# How do I do a redirect/rewrite rule for S3 using s3_website?

Tags: macos, redirect, amazon-s3

I am migrating from a hosted site to hosting wordpress in s3.  One of the things I'd like to do is have a folder at the root level into which I can put all the files.  This makes it easier to delete if I need to.

The problem is that my prior has the format of blog.site.com/post.

If I put all the posts in a separate folder, the format shows up as blog.site.com/folder/post

**Question:** Is there a way to write a rewrite rule using s3_website to **rewrite/redirect blog.site.com/folder/post to blog.site.com/post?**

This is based on the sample code from s3_website:

```
routing_rules:
- condition:      
    key_prefix_equals: site/folder    
  redirect:      
    host_name: www.site.com     
    replace_key_prefix_with: /      
    http_redirect_code: 301
```

When I try it, I get an error.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for key_prefix_equals

```
key_prefix_equals: folder/
```

I am **not** positive this is the correct solution.